# If I uninstall then reinstall Outlook 2007, will it be in the exact same state when I open it again?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, microsoft-office-2007

I'm having some serious computer problems that I'm tempted to blame on Office, so I'd like to uninstall and reinstall to see (or to rule it out). That said, Outlook is my life, so if it gets screwed up (or reset to defaults) in the process, it probably won't be worth it to me.

Note that I just have configuration settings and all my emails/info/folders, no add-ons or plugins.

So: if I uninstall Office 2007 and reinstall it, when I open Outlook again for the first time, will everything be exactly the way it was before I did this?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried a Repair of the Office install.  That has often solved issues for me.  In Control Panel, Add/Remove programs click on Office and then Change. Click radio button reinstall or repair.  Click next and let it run.

Alos, do you have latest servcie packs and patches installed?

Answer (score 1):

If you uninstall outlook, it will not be exactly the same.  You will lose everything, usually the most important thing that everyone cries about is the ost file which is what holds all your previously typed email addresses.

Comment: 1. The ost file doesn't hold previously typed email addresses, the NK2 file does. 2. An ost file is only used when you connect Outlook to an Exchange server and Outlook is configured in cached mode.

Answer (score 0):

If you uninstall and then reinstall, I highly doubt that it'll be exactly the same.  What you'd be missing would depend on how you have your email setup but more than likely...

1. You'll need to setup your email account again.
2. You'll have to reopen any additional PST files you're using.
3. Any rules and alerts you've setup will most likely also be missing.
4. ...

Answer (score 0):

if Outlook is your life you should frequently backup your mails and account settings, here's a brief **[tutorial](http://www.sitedeveloper.ws/tutorials/outlook.htm)**.

having such a backup will make any reinstallation a painless process.